# Setar bearing utilizando o CameraUpdate

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Tenho duas posições (`LatLong`) que gostaria de centraliza-las no mapa!

Para isso, faço o seguinte:

```
 final LatLngBounds.Builder builderZoom = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        if(null != mCurrentLocation){
            builderZoom.include(new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
        if(null != mLocation){
            builderZoom.include(new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
        final CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builderZoom.build(), 55);
        mMap.moveCamera(cu);
```

Até aí tudo bem!

Agora preciso atualizar o `bearing` do mapa, e faço da seguinte forma:

```
   CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().
                                target(new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude())).
                                zoom(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom).
                                bearing(mCurrentBearing).
                                build();
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Neste caso, passo o `target` que anula a primeira parte!

Gostaria de saber se:
Posso passar um `LatLngBounds` em um `CameraPosition` ao invés do `target`?

Ou se em um `CameraUpdate` posso modificar o `bearing`?